# How to select multiple values with join in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have a database called "forum" with the tables:

- "users", containing: user_id, username, password
- "posts", containing: post_id, user_id (FK from "users"), type, title, content
- "comments", containing: comment_id, user_id (FK from "users"), post_id (FK from posts"), content

At the moment, i'm using the query:

```
SELECT *
FROM forum.comments 
JOIN forum.posts ON (comments.post_id = posts.post_id) 
JOIN forum.users ON (posts.user_id= users.user_id)
```

With this query i can only display the username of the person who made the post, not the comment. How can i change this to show who made the comment, AND who made the post in the same query?

(If someething in the query is written wrong, it's just cause i had to translate it from another language, the query does return results).

Comment: was not aware of that option, thanks Gordon Linoff

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can join the table more than once if you alias the tables:

```
SELECT * FROM forum.comments AS c
JOIN forum.posts AS p ON (comments.post_id = posts.post_id)
JOIN forum.users AS u1 ON (posts.user_id = users.user_id)
JOIN forum.users AS u2 ON (comments.user_id = users.user_id)
```

When you do that, you can reference columns from the table by doing something like `SELECT u1.username, u2.username ...`.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply! :)

Comment: To increase readability i would use the aliases `up` (user of post) instead of `u1` and `uc` (user of comment) instead of `u2`.